# Can't upgrade Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.3 to 17.04

Tags: 16.04, gnome, upgrade, 17.04

I cannot upgrade Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.3 to 17.04.  I have switched the setting in Software & Updates to **Notify me of a new Ubuntu version: For any new version**, I also tried editing  `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and verified that `Prompt=normal` was indeed set.

I run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

then

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

but it always returns:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release.
```

This is not a duplicate of the previous question;  the path for Ubuntu GNOME is 16.04.3 to 17.04. There is no 16.10 release of Ubuntu GNOME, so I'm not skipping any release versions.

Comment: You can't upgrade from 16.04 to 17.04, and it is a bad idea to upgrade an LTS to a non-LTS release. It makes no sense.

Comment: I believe the path aught to be `16.04` --> `16.10` --> `17.04`, but note non-lts versions

Comment: 16.10 is EOL, so there is no path.

Comment: The path is not true for Ubuntu Gnome.  You must go 16.04.3 to 17.04.  There is no 16.10 release of Ubuntu Gnome.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/YakketyYak/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuGNOME  Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 did indeed exist.

Comment: @Pilot6 why updating from LTS to non-LTS is a bad idea and makes no sense?

Comment: What is the reason to do that? There is no value in it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

do `sudo update-manager -c` in order to update from 16.04 to 17.04

Comment: This is a wrong answer.

Comment: no it is not a worng answer I just updated from 16.04 to 17.04 yesterday!

Comment: Its my pleasure to help you

Comment: Also worked for me! Updated from 16.04 LTS to 17.04. Thanks

Comment: You may have to reboot it a few times but it will grab the upgrade in the end. However you are jumping on with a development distribution - so don't do this to your production installs.